# Exchange 2007: smartphone syncing options

Tags: exchange-2007, synchronization, iphone, smartphone

Consider a deployment of Exchange 2007. OWA is deployed and working well. Users want to sync their smartphones with their Exchange account (mail, contacts, calendar mostly). The Exchange configuration details on the phones are using the `webmail.company.com` public OWA address.

Questions:

- are there options for **enabling/disabling** sync for smartphones (iPhone specifically, but considering Blackberry also)
- is there a way to specify whether they're able to sync or not **based on their address** (e.g. allow syncing on via LAN address, but not on a public address?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can configure separate ActiveSync policies (a default of disabled and a second one for enabled) in the Exchange Management Console -> Organizationl Configuration -> Client Access.  If you make the default disabled you would just need to assign the "enabled" policy to the mailbox accounts which you want to allow to sync.
2. I'm not aware of any way to restrict this through policy and I'm not sure why you would want to.  You could just block it at the firewall I suppose.

Comment: Combine my answer and yours and I think he has a solution!

Answer (score 2):

You could probably do this by only allowing local LAN IPs access to the IIS ActiveSync folder and blocking everything else.

I block Blackberry BIS access to OWA with this method.

Also...I personally would never allow an employee to keep company email on a personal device that I couldn't at the very least enforce password policy on and wipe remotely if lost or stolen.  You should look at an ActiveSync or BES solution.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange 2007 cannot sync Blackberrys without the help of a 3rd party solution, typically a blackberry enterprise server.

Comment: True, but every Blackberry on BIS has the ability to sync through OWA if not on the BES

Comment: That's not a true sync, it's only mail.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the blackberry device, but for iPhone device, while synchronizing with Exchange, various issues arise such as

a) Account Configuration Issue
b) Synchronization Problems Occur in Outlook
c) Repeat or Duplicate Contacts After Syncing
d) Can not Remove contacts across multiple devices

[image]

To fix the above problem, you need to carefully create and synchronize the Exchange account with iPhone device, to configure properly [**Check**](https://www.datarecovery.institute/exchange-contacts-not-syncing-iphone/) out the steps.
Hope for iPhone device, information helps: